# Como usar a tag output?

Tags: html, html5

Copiei esse exemplo de um site porém não funciona.

```
<form oninput="result.value=parseInt(a.value)+parseInt(b.value)">
 0<input type="range" name="b" value="50" />100 +<input type="number" name="a" value="10" /> =
 <output name="result"></output>
</form>
```

Comment: Funciona bem para mim: https://jsfiddle.net/516sr92d/ O que não funciona para ti? Que browser estás a usar?

Comment: Aqui também funcionou como esperado, Chrome, versão 57.0.2987.133

Comment: Também funciona pra mim, vale lembrar que que o suporte pelos browsers é atualmente limitado. Dá uma olhada aqui: http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic

Comment: Furo meu, estava testando no meu editor de texto, o qual sempre testei códigos e funcionam, porém esse não,  postei no servidor e funcionou,

Comment: Muita interessante a tag, desconhecia. Quando foi adicionada?

Comment: Não sei dizer peguei nesse link  https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output

Comment: @lazyFox são as tags novas do HTML 5, dá uma olhada aqui https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

Comment: W3Schools: _The output element is not supported in Edge 12 or Internet Explorer and earlier versions._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O mais provável, é que seu navegador esteja desatualizado e não esteja aceitando o `<output>`.

Recomendo que verifique a versão do seu Browser para ter certeza que ele tem suporte a essa tag. Nesse link é possivel ver as versões em que o `<output>` já é suportado e detalhes: [Browser Support](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_output.asp)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra possibilidade é seu servidor não estar aceitando a tag; em alguns casos a tag não está funcionando localmente, isso deve-se a diferentes versões.

> Recomendo que teste em outros navegadores e em diferentes versões, pois o mais provável é a incompatibilidade do navegador.

Espero ter ajudado.