# Pra que serve a tag <output>?

Tags: html, html5

Gostaria de saber para que serve a tag `<output>`.

Vi esse exemplo aqui na internet:

```html
<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="o.value = a.valueAsNumber + b.valueAsNumber">
  <input name="a" type="number" step="any"> +
  <input name="b" type="number" step="any"> =
  <output name="o" for="a b"></output>
</form>
```

Olhando o exemplo acima, percebi que essa propriedade `value` é algo que não existe nos demais elementos normalmente.  Geralmente, você tem a propriedade `value` no `input`, mas é interessante ver que na tag `output` também tenha.

Queria entender um pouco mais sobre a mesma para saber se posso usar ela no meu dia a dia.

- Qual é a finalidade dessa tag?
- Quais é a diferença de escrever um valor numa tag `<output>` para as demais tags? Ou seja, não bastava apenas usar `innerText`?

**Observação**: Até cheguei a ver que no site tem uma pergunta [sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197592/como-usar-a-tag-output), porém não há uma resposta sobre a finalidade da tag.

Comment: **Leia com atenção**: Algumas perguntas, por mais simples que pareçam, são feitas por mim para ajudar agregar conteúdo [em nossa língua pátria] ao site.

Comment: Wallace vc pegou o dicionário do html hoje? :D

Comment: @hugocsl [sim](https://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#elementdef-output)

Comment: Vamos alfabetizar o SOPT

Comment: Gostei da iniciativa, a galera do Ctrl+C Ctrl+V precisa ver os fundamentos tb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De forma resumida, a tag `<output>` é como a tag `<input>` com o atributo `readonly`. O valor dele pode ser enviado via requisição do formulário, então não bastava apenas um `innerText`, já que em outras tags, como uma `div`, o valor não seria enviado.

Diferente do `<input type=readonly>`, ele vai suportar *"quebras de linha"*, ou seja vai poder escrever outras tags HTML dentro livremente (claro que no envio será tratado como texto). Ele também não tem visual de `input` (aparência), é semelhante a um elemento normal, mas interage com o `<form>`, ou seja ele **não é exclusivamente** utilizado para representar cálculos, isso é apenas parte do que ele pode fazer.

Incluindo que o `<output>` suporta o atributo `form=""` que pode ser uma grande vantagem, ou seja o `<form>` pode estar em um lugar e o output em outro:

```
<form id="meuForm">
...
</form>

...

<output form="meuForm"></output>
```

Ele suporta também [validação e a propriedade `defaultValue`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-output-element) para acaso altere o valor ainda poderia saber qual o valor inicial (original).

Answer (score 0):

O elemento `output`, lido como saída na língua portuguesa, é geralmente utilizado para representar o resultado de um cálculo.

Exemplo de uso: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_output

Assim como outros elementos HTML, o `output` aceita os atributos `for`, `form` e `name`.

Vale ressaltar que essa tag não funciona em qualquer navegador.

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output

Comment: Na w3c, vi um exemplo mostrando o resultado de um dado vindo do websocket. Não creio que seja um caso especificamente restrito a cálculos.

Comment: É, a [documentação em português da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output) realmente deixa a desejar

Comment: @WallaceMaxters sim, está bem fraca a documentação, mas de qualquer forma, eu não disse que é restrito a cálculos, eu disse que é geralmente utilizado para, são coisas diferentes :)